# Auto complete textbox in C# winform with drag and drop?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, controls

Does C# has a built-in auto complete textbox which we can drag and drop in winform design like other controls ?

If there isn't can we create an auto complete textbox manually then put it in the toolbox ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is built into Windows and always available, much like the mouse cursor and the caret.  You don't explicitly drag it on a form.  Set the TextBox' AutoComplete properties to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

try to see this example of code.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Esempio-di-autocompletament-e47dee78

Regards.

Comment: Note this requires a database with the autocomplete data and the example in in VB (not C#). So maybe this is not what Sun wants.